# Angular how to keep hashtag in html5 mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-routing

In Angular router, if you turn on html5 mode, you automatically remove the hashtags in urls, which is great. But what, if you want to keep hashtags for non router related things, for example, if you want to scroll to an image with a specific id?

www.example.com#imageId becomes www.example.com/imageId, which is not the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned with anchor scrolling, you don't necessarily need url location hashtags to scroll to elements. You can use $anchorScroll('elementId') inside a controller method to do that. I just did this yesterday in a project at work.

[Angular Docs Link to $anchorScroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll)

Comment: that's true, but the purpose of hash tags is for users to be able to scroll to the image just by going to a specific link. Since there can be many elements/images on a page it wouldn't be practical to have a non-hashtag link for each element.

Comment: In our application, scrolling to specific elements is rare (mainly scrolling up to top on certain events). If you have a lot of anchors, I agree that this may not be practical. Note that $anchorScroll is not link-based, and assumes you are processing an event like a click via a method in your controller.